# Move visual studio site workflow to the host web

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have used following code it is working fine for the list workflow now I have to move my site workflow but it is not getting attached to the site. I have tried with changing the `source_id` to site GUID instead of the list GUID.

```
function TestWorkflow() {
        var xaml = workflowDefinition.get_xaml();// getting xaml of workflow here
        var historyListId = "{...}"; // History List ID. Already exists

        var tasklistId = "{...}";
        jQuery.getScript("/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js", function () {
            var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var servicesManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web());

            var definition = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowDefinition.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web());
            definition.set_xaml(xaml);
            definition.set_displayName("Test1234");
            definition.set_restrictToType('List');
            var deploymentService = servicesManager.getWorkflowDeploymentService();
            deploymentService.saveDefinition(definition);
            ctx.load(definition, "Id");

            var targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
            ctx.load(targetList, 'Id');

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                deploymentService.publishDefinition(definition.get_id());

                ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    var subscription = new SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscription(ctx);

                    subscription.set_name("Test1234");
                    subscription.set_enabled(true);
                    subscription.set_definitionId(definition.get_id());
                    subscription.set_eventSourceId(targetList.get_id());
                    subscription.set_eventTypes(["ItemAdded"]);
                    subscription.setProperty("TaskListId", tasklistId);
                    subscription.setProperty("HistoryListId", historyListId);
                    subscription.setProperty("FormData", "");

                    var subscriptionService = servicesManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService();
                    subscriptionService.publishSubscriptionForList(subscription, targetList.get_id());

                    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                        console.log("done");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there any another way other than set_eventSourceId(). Anything other property do we need to set for site workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 changes we have to do for it.

1. `subscription.set_eventSourceId(targetList.get_id())` use `subscription.set_eventSourceId(web.get_id())//Set GUID of site(load web object above).`
2. use `hostWebSubscriptionService.publishSubscription(subscription, web.get_id());` instead of `subscriptionService.publishSubscriptionForList(subscription, targetList.get_id())`